# Losing format excel cell using replace from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I'm using a excel template with labels that must be replaced with input values using VBA.

To do that I used the:

```
Cells.Replace What:="&/TDT/&", Replacement:="123456987654321456654444", _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:= _
        True, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

But the displayed value in the cell after execute this replace is 1,23457E+23. I've tried to use different formats in the cell settings and I tried to change the ReplaceFormat and SeachFormat parameters without changes in the result.

Anyone has idea why excel doesn't respect the format of the cell?

The used format is Text for the replaced cell and the version of Office is 2007/2010. What I need is to see in the cell the 123456987654321456654444 instead of 1,23457E+23 after replacement.

Comment: This is hard, as Excel's strongest instinct is to convert anything that looks a bit like a number into a number! I've tried various, with no success. The only thing you can do is put a single quote at the start of your string "'1234....", which will not appear on the worksheet, but will be present in the  value, so not really the value you want to store.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to combine using `Value` property and `Find` method to implement safe (or safer) replace like this:

```vb
Sub SafeReplace(ByVal What As String, ByVal Replacement As String)
    Set cell = Cells.Find(What:=What, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Do While Not cell Is Nothing
        cell.Value = Replacement
        Set cell = Cells.FindNext(cell)
    Loop
End Sub
```

And then use it

```vb
SafeReplace "&/TDT/&", "123456987654321456654444"
```

It should respect the format of the cell.

Comment: @Rafael Chacon Did it help?

Answer (score 0):

`'` can be used in front of values to treat them as text:

```
Cells.Replace What:="&/TDT/&", Replacement:="'123456987654321456654444"
```